# .htaccess rewriting ALL urls

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm working on a team that gives me limited access to the server (long story).  My assignment is to get .htaccess to rewrite URLs in a subdirectory (http://www.myserver.com/subdirectory).  This shouldn't be a big deal, except the rules seem to be rewriting all of the URLs, not just those matching the patterns.

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)\.html$ products.php?pr_category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ products.php?pr_category=$1&pr_subcategory=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ products.php?pr_category=$1&pr_subcategory=$2&pr_name=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^tech_resource/([^/]*)\.html$ tech_resource.php?tr_category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tech_resource/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ tech_resource.php?tr_category=$1&tr_name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)\.html$ news.php?ne_name=$1 [L]
```

Everything seems to be just fine, except that ***all*** of the page URLs get rewritten like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory/products/category/subcateogry/images/image.jpg
```

That is the rewrite is inserting the contents of $1, $2, and $3 into every url path.  These should simply be:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory/images/image.jpg
```

What am I missing?  Could it be something in the root .htaccess?

Comment: The rewrite rules you have provided will rewrite URLs that end with .html ONLY -- they simply cannot rewrite .jpg files. I suggest checking for more rewrite rules somewhere else (different folders, server config maybe). If you want to check that these rules do not do that -- comment them out and check if images are still being rewritten.

Comment: That's what I thought... I'm trying to find out if there are any root .htaccess rules that are doing something weird before it gets to this directory.

Comment: Hmmmm.... the root .htaccess is empty.  The site is on a hosted server.

Comment: Comment out all YOUR rules and see if that still messes up with images. If yes -- it has nothing to do with your rules. If no -- enable 1 rule and test again. Repeat until reproduced.

Comment: I commented out all the rules except one:
    RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ products.php?pr_category=$1&pr_subcategory=$2&pr_name=$3 [L]

The redirect works, except, again, it's rewriting the image URLs, too.  Most goofy.

Comment: If you comment out ALL rules -- is it still happening? If no -- No idea then -- you really need turn on rewritting debug (need to be able edit Apache config), otherwise I cannot offer you any sensible advices .. as I see NO way how that particular rule can rewrite .jpg images ...

Comment: Comment out all rules, then everything comes up fine, but no rewriting ;).

I'm trying to figure out if there aren't some server side settings  goofing things up.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can offer you this rule (place it before your other rules) -- this will tell Apache to not to touch any image files (files with such extensions) during rewrite stage: `RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png|ico)$ - [L, NC]`

Comment: I'm still struggling with the rewrites adding "products" to every URL, even with the added rule to exclude the images.

There is something happening server side that's not playing nice with the normal .htaccess rules and configurations.

Comment: Well -- based on the info you have provided I have no clue what that may be (you said that there s=is no other rules/.htaccess files around). Only rewrite debugging may help you here, but that is impossible to turn ON on shared hosting. I really suggest to search for ALL .htaccess files, even if it is folder above or so.

Comment: On another hand -- maybe you should check how images (links to images) are written on the actual page? **Check the HTML code of the page itself.** What I'm thinking -- they are written with relative paths, which can cause similar issues with URL rewriting involved. You have to use links **relative to the website root** (with leading slash, e.g. `<img src="/images/logo.png" />`) instead of relative to the current page (e.g. `<img src="images/logo.png" />`). Otherwise -- create rule to rewrite images to a proper location (i.e. strip `/products/category/subcateogry` part off).

Comment: That's it!  I'm not responsible for the code, but now need to get those who are to fix it.  I owe you a drink!